# Implicit differentiation of the function defined by the equation $y^2 = x^2 + \sin(xy)$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

During implicit differentiation of this problem: $y^2 = x^2 + \sin(xy)$

I cannot figure out why at this point in differentiation this:

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x + \left(\cos xy\right) \left(y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

changes to:

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}- \left(\cos xy\right) \left(x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x + \left(\cos xy\right)y$$

If they subtracted the $\cos xy$ from one side why is it still on the other?

Comment: $(\cos xy)(y+x)\frac{\mathbb d y}{\mathbb d x}$ is two terms: $y(\cos xy)\frac{\mathbb d y}{\mathbb d x}$ and $x(\cos xy)\frac{\mathbb d y}{\mathbb d x}$. A better question is 'where has the $\frac{\mathbb d y}{\mathbb d x}$ gone from the right hand side?'

Comment: Part of your expression is wrong. It should be $\cos(xy)\left(y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$.

Comment: Have you tried distributing $\cos(xy)$ over $y + x\dfrac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: Why does it turn into y + x if using the product rule on (xy) should generate zero?

Comment: Remember that $y$ is a function of $x$.  The product rule says that $(f \cdot g)' = f'g + fg'$.  Here, $f = x$ and $g = y$.  Thus, $$(xy)' = \left(\frac{d}{dx}x\right)y + x\frac{d}{dx}y = 1y + x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: yes I see thanks. Somehow was thinking deriv of variable was 0, but that is for constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &= 2x + (\cos xy)(y+x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}) &&\text{Initial equation} \\
2y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &= 2x + (\cos xy)(y) + (\cos xy)(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &&\text{Expand \((y+x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx})\)} \\
2y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} - (\cos xy)(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &= 2x + (\cos xy)(y) &&\text{Subtract \((\cos xy)(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\)}
\end{align*}

**The point to note:** $\cos xy$ is not standing on its own; instead, it is multiplied by a polynomial which, when expanded, becomes the sum of two terms:

$$
(\cos xy)(y) + (\cos xy)(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}
$$

both of which having $\cos xy$ as a factor. Thus, the term that is subtracted from both sides (and eliminated on the right side) of the equation is not $\cos xy$ but instead $(\cos xy)(x)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$.